# Predicition interval for LOESS smoothed data

Tags: predictive-models, loess

Is the concept of a prediction interval for non-parameteric fits such as LOESS meaningful? I can't see why it wouldn't be - and the fact that it is implemented in R also implies it is.

https://mclust-org.github.io/msir/reference/loess.sd.html

But I can't find any reference on how to derive it (including in the book referenced in the link above) however, which makes me think I am missing something - unlike for parameteric modelling where the prediction interval is heavily documented.

I would like to derive prediction intervals for a various fitting techniques, including LOESS, which is why I'd like to understand it better- guidance welcome

Comment: You're correct.  The *concept* of a prediction interval is independent of any model you might be working with.

Comment: Perfect thanks - do you know of any references that explain how to go about the implementation of the prediction interval with LOESS? My googling wasnt very productive..

Comment: Loess is an exploratory tool.  Any prediction interval offered by software ought to be viewed as a kind of *ad hoc* sketch that might, on occasion, be useful as an indicator of the magnitude of local variation.  If you need a true nonparametric prediction interval related to Loess, then bootstrapping would be an attractive method.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, the specific function you've linked basically calculates the [non-parametric variance function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_function#Non-parametric_regression_analysis) of the Loess fit.

The intervals constructed are referred to as *variance smooths* by Cook & Weisberg (1999, pp. 52 - 53) for the Loess, and are calculated as:

$$\hat{E}(y | x) \pm \sqrt{\widehat{Var}(y | x)}$$

Where $\hat{E}(y | x)$ is the estimated mean function and $\sqrt{\widehat{Var}(y | x)}$ is the estimated standard deviation function, calculated by a procedure as follows (outlined in Section 2.5.2 of the same text, pp. 36 - 37):

1. Calculate $E(y | x)$ using Loess with a given smoothing parameter, $\alpha$
2. Create a new variable representing the squared deviation of each observation from the mean function

$$\hat{e}^2 = (y - \hat{E}(y | x))^2$$

3. Calculate $\hat{E}(\hat{e}^2 | x)$ using Loess with the same $\alpha$ - this is our estimate of $\widehat{Var}(y | x)$ and conceptually is like smoothing a scatterplot of the squared deviations on $x$
4. Take the square root of the variance function to calculate the standard deviation function

If you dig into the `loess.sd` function in `msir`, you'll find this is basically what it does (also allowing you to scale the standard deviation function using the `nsigma` argument).

But I'll work through an example manually using R to demonstrate. I'm using the cholesterol data from the `bootstrap` package which evaluated the effects of cholostyramine compliance on blood cholesterol levels.

```r
# Load the Data
cholesterol <- bootstrap::cholost
colnames(cholesterol) <- c("compliance", "improvement")
with(cholesterol, plot(compliance, improvement))

# 1. Fit loess to find mean function E(y | x)
alpha <- 0.6
m1 <- loess(improvement ~ compliance, 
            data = cholesterol,
            span = alpha)

# Generate and plot predictions from mean function
new_dat <- data.frame(compliance = seq(0, 100))
preds <- predict(m1, new_dat)
lines(seq(0, 100), preds)

# 2. Find squared deviations
cholesterol$e <- residuals(m1)^2

# 3. Fit loess to find variance function E(e^2 | x)
m2 <- loess(e ~ compliance, 
            data = cholesterol,
            span = alpha)

# 4. Estimate Std. Deviation function across values of x
sd <- sqrt(predict(m2, new_dat))

# Find upper and lower limits and plot
ll <- preds - sd
ul <- preds + sd
lines(new_dat$compliance, ll, lty = 2)
lines(new_dat$compliance, ul, lty = 2)
```

Which graphically looks like this:

[image]

---

##### References

Cook, R. D., & Weisberg, S. (1999). [Applied regression including computing and graphics](http://doi.org/10.1002/9780470316948). John Wiley & Sons.

Comment: Thats fantastic thanks. I'm actually having to implement it in .NET, not R which is why the explanation and references are particularly useful. Cheers!